# Glyphicon in responsive header

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css

Is it possible to have a user `glyphicon` in a responsive header which when hovered shows the credentials of the user logged in?

I want the user `glyphicon` only to appear when I resize the screen next to the hamburger icon(menu). Please help?

Comment: you can use @mediaquery for (glyphicon only to appear )

Comment: As per my understanding you want to show `user glyphicon` on mobile or tablet devices right? Then what is the point of hovering there unless you have a stylus!! Click might be possible to work around with!!

Comment: @GuruprasadRao Yes, you are right. A click will work. But how do I wrap the text into glyphicon on mobile or tablet? I have a Welcome message like: Welcome User on the right corner of the header now which I want to turn in to a glyphicon, which when clicked must show that Welcome User message in a pop-up or something.

Comment: you mean outside the `navbar`??

Comment: and can you use query to show the element on click??

Comment: yes, out side the nav bar